# Type of error for assigning Base class objects with Derived class objects

Tags: c++

I just wanted to know the errors we would get if a derived class object is assigned to a variable from its base class.

Would it be a syntax error or a compile run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. But it's *not* normal or good practice.

What happens is that the derived class is "sliced" to *become* an object of the base class.

What is common is when you assign a pointer/reference to a derived object to a pointer/reference to the base. *That* forms the basis of C++'s run-time polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You can force a compiler to trigger an error when such assignment is encountered:

```
class Derived;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;

    Base(const Derived &d) = delete;
    Base& operator=(const Derived& other) = delete;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base b = d;
}
```

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/gM11Hf)